# Duplex + Silverlight + WCF + Pulling data

Tags: silverlight, wcf, data-binding, duplex

I've been looking for it, for quite and while, and I didn't really find anything that cover how to pull data trough duplex connection for Silverlight (pollingHttpDuplex).

I have setup basic sub/pub application with duplex.

Now I wanted to get list of topics, that are users are connected to. My first thought, was to setup simple DataContract (with only one field TopicName), then get data from Dicionary that I've been using to store current topics.
So I end up with something like this:

```
[OperationContract]        
public List<Topic> GetTopicList()
{
    List<Topic> topicList;

    topicList = (from p in _sessionIDTopic
                select new Topic
                {
                    TopicName = p.Value
                }).ToList<Topic>();

    return topicList;
}

[DataContract]
public class Topic
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong here. Because big question is how to send this to the client (Silverlight 4), and bind it to controls ?

Also duplex is essential for application. Changing it for anything else is not an option.

Comment: There must be so called CallbackContract. In that interface you can define any methods which you can call on the server side and they will be executed on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a duplex connection here doesn't have any effect on how you get the data to the client. The example you specified looks like simple one way communication. To do that, your client project needs a service reference to the server, and the generated proxy will provide the methods the client needs to access the operations on the server.

I think you should start by looking at a simple WCF example project to see what I mean. If this is not your problem, please rephrase the question.